# Combining a partial variable and a whole variable to get a dynamic variable?

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to figure out a really simple section of code in a massive project I am working on, but just can't get this to work...

```
<?php
  $this2="squirrel";
  $i=2;
  $trythis = "$"."this$i";
  echo $trythis;
?>
```

With this script, it shows $this2 instead of squirrel...

I need the output to be squirrel, but all I can seem to get is syntax errors or a printout "$this2".

I have been working on this for about 3 hours, and have tried every combination of everything I can think of, plus its well after midnight, and I have been up for 20 hours at this point...

Comment: You're looking for "variable variable". Avoid using variable variable as much as possible because code based on that usually get messy/smelly/hard-to-read most of the time.

Comment: basically what I am doing is inputting into a database from my ESP8266.
i have 4 aquariums being controlled through it, from lighting; fading on/off and timers, to heaters.
for each tank temperature, I have a variable: current temp tank 1 = ctT1, current temp tank 2 = ctT2, etc. I need to write the values that the ESP8266 retrieves into the 4 different tables, so I ended up writing a multi-row update script, but couldnt figure out (or was too tired to figure out) how to add 1 to each $ctT variable to get the $_GET value.

the 2 posts below work, and are super simple

Comment: rather, that should say "ESP8266 retrieves into the 4 different *rows within my table*"

Answer (score 2):

You use incorrect syntax - don't nead to make dollar sing as string. Should be

```
 $trythis = ${"this$i"};
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/931769)

Comment: This works great! I didnt try {} but i did try everything else haha. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$this2="squirrel";
 $i=2;
 $trythis = "this$i";
 echo $$trythis;`

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation on how your code answers the question.

Comment: this works awesome. im really glad it was that easy haha! i even tried using $$, but not this way. cheers!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **why** and **how** this code answers the question improves its long-term value.